# Updating session variables with AJAX request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

Here is the problem. I need to call "reset.php" script with AJAX request and reset session variables to initial values there. 
Now, it looks like this:

index.php:

```
<?php session_start();
    $_SESSION['var'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['var'] = 1;
?>
<button>reset</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("button").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "reset.php",
            success: function(){
                    //some function
                }
            });         
    });
</script>
```

reset.php

```
<?php session_start();
    $_SESSION['var'] = 0;
?>
```

That's not working, "success" runs properly, but session variables stays the same. What may be the problem?

Comment: after submitting, are you refreshing the index.php?

Comment: What if you echo the session variable in `reset.php` and make a `console.log(response)` in the success

Comment: The session variables are only read when the page is first rendered. The AJAX request will not affect that at all. If you need to read the updated value (which is a little redundant as you just made a call to set the explicit value) return the data to the AJAX request. That being said, you seem a little confused about the difference between client and server side logic. I'd suggest doing some research in that area.

Comment: your code is working fine, if u add 1 line in reset.php `print_r($_SESSION);` and change index.php as `success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });`

Comment: @devpro, no, page must work without refreshing

Comment: yes i tried your code without refreshing the page, and its working fine. and session return ma value `0`

Comment: @executable it shows whole code of reset.php in console, not echoed value

Comment: Do you have PHP installed ?

Comment: @executable yes

Comment: I have found my mistake, that was really stupid one, thanks everybody for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session variables are only read when the page is first rendered. The AJAX request will not affect that at all. If you need to read the updated value (which is a little redundant as you just made a call to set the explicit value) return the data to the AJAX request. That being said, you seem a little confused about the difference between client and server side logic. I'd suggest doing some research in that area. – as  Rory McCrossan said in the comment.

```
    <?php session_start();
        if(isset($_SESSION['var'])) {
              $_SESSION['var'] = 0;
        }else {
            $_SESSION['var'] = 1;
            }
        ?>
        <button>reset</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("button").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "reset.php",
                    success: function(res){
                            alert(res);
    if(res) { 
    location.reload();  // but AJAX means without reload                        
     //<?  $_SESSION['var']; ?> = res; will not work            
    // you cannot set PHP value here, you need to do it with javascript if you want to set the value anywhere on this page

}
                        }
                    });         
            });
        </script>
```

your php

```
<?php session_start();
    $_SESSION['var'] = 0;
    echo  $_SESSION['var'];
?>
```

you can use redirect

```
<?php session_start();
        $_SESSION['var'] = 0;
       header("url of the above page");
    ?>
```

Comment: Nice code dump, you could at least explain what's going on here and what's different from OP's code...

Comment: @Adam that is enough explanation?

Comment: Looks good! It's always helpful to add some comments and explanation so that OP and others that come across this can understand different solutions. Good job!